# Suitescript: Popup when item is added on sales order

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want a popup to appear when certain items are added to a sales order in Netsuite. The popup shall appear on create and edit. In my code so far, I want the popup to appear when item number 5071, 1337 or 12345 is added to a sales order. But nothing happens when I've deployed the script. I have deployed it for all roles on the sales order record. I got the script from https://netsuiteprofessionals.com/question/popup-message-on-sales-order-when-certain-item-added/ but tweeked it a little bit.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? And how do I add so that the script logs each time it has shown a message?

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.0
* @NScriptType ClientScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(['N/ui/dialog','N/record','N/currentRecord'], 
function (dialog, record, currentRecord) {
    function validateLine(context) {
        var soRecord = context.currentRecord;
        var list = context.sublistId === 'items';
        var itemsArray = [507000, 124, 125];
        var currentItem;
        if (list) {
            currentItem = soRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'items',
                fieldId: 'item'
            });
            if (itemsArray.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1) {
                dialog.alert({
            title: 'Question?',
            message: 'Please confirm this and that.'
                }).then(success).catch(failure);
            }
        }
    }
    function success() {
        return success;
    
    }
    function failure() {

        return false;

    }
    return {
validateLine : validateLine
    };
});
```

Comment: How many client scripts do you have deployed on the Sales Order record?

Comment: We have 14 now...  Googled and found that 10 can be maximum. Is that true? We are 6 subsidiaries and not all subs are using all scripts. Do they count deployed scripts per subsidiary?

Comment: Since I'm in sandbox I undeployed many of the scripts. Now something happens when I add a new line. But the outcome is not the wanted one. Now I can not press "add", nothing happens.

Comment: Correct - only 10 client scripts will run.  See answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is an arbitrary maximum of 10 client scripts supported.  If your script is eleventh, or further down on the Client Scripts subtab of the Scripted Records page, it will not run.  (This may depend whether the scripts above it are all deployed - I don't know every nuance of how the 10 are counted).  You can change the order of scripts to ensure more important ones are run by Editing the Scripted Record page, selecting the line for the script you want to reorder and then drag the handle (6 dots at the left).

To work around the "10 script limit", you can refactor your client scripts to include more functionality in a single script.  This can still be an issue if you have many bundles/SuiteApps installed with locked client scripts, but you can choose which ones to prioritize.

Another issue you have is here:

```
 if (list) {
        currentItem = soRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'items', //ON THIS LINE
            fieldId: 'item'
        });
        if (itemsArray.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1) {
            dialog.alert({
        title: 'Question?',
        message: 'Please confirm this and that.'
            }).then(success).catch(failure);
        }
    }
```

Your `alert` function runs *conditionally* based on the `currentItem` being present.  However, `currentItem` depends on a value being pulled from the `items` sublist, which does not exist. The correct sublist ID is `item`.

Comment: Thank you for your insights Krypton. I also changed it to here "var list = context.sublistId === 'item';

But it's still not possible to add an item to an order. Nothing happens when I press enter..

Comment: Did you also change the value for `sublistId` in the `getCurrentSublistValue` function?

Comment: Try adding some console logging in at various points to see if it's passing the `if` statements.  Or remove the `if`s one at a time (change them to `if (true) ` to try to isolate which, if any, of them are causing the issue.

Comment: I just noticed something else: a `validateLine` entry point script must `return true` to indicate the line is valid.  change your `success` function to `return true;` rather than `return success;`

Comment: Thank you!

I changed to "return true" instead of "return success". I also tried out the if statements like you said, and if I change "if (itemsArray.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1)" to "if (true)" I receive the popup when I try to add whatever item. So there is one problem. Another problem is when I press "OK" in the popup, the line is not added. Do I need to add something in my success function?

Comment: I think what might be happening is that the `return true;` goes back to the `dialog.alert` function, but is not returned to the `validateLine` function.  Try adding `return` before `dialog.alert`  - ( `return dialog.alert(options)` )

Comment: @JeppePeppe I'm curious whether you ended up getting this working.